# Separating a string that is duplicated using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, explode

The variable $category is received as "summersummer" or "all-seasonall-season".

Is there any way for me to split this? I am trying to pass it on as a term.

Here is my code.

```
function advanced_search_query($query) {

if($query->is_search()) {
    // category terms search.
    $category = $_GET['category'];
    $string_array = explode(" ",$category);
    print_r($string_array);
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    if (isset($category) && !empty($category)) {
        $args = array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $category
            )
        );
        $query->set('tax_query', $args);
    }
    return $query;
} } add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query', 1000);
```

The print_r gives me Array ( [0] => all-season ) Array ( [0] => all-season )

EDIT 1 (The code sending the value for $category):

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php print_r( $query ); ?><?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ); ?>">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Products&hellip;', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
<select name="category">
    <option value="winter">Winter</option>
    <option value="all-season">All Season</option>
    <option value="run-flat">Run Flats</option>
    <option value="summer">Summer</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
```

Comment: Where do you have $category containing the content twice? According to print_r you have only "summer" or "all-season" in it, but your function is called twice. Otherwise print_r would give you Array ([0] => all-seasonall-season) or Array[0] => all-season, [1] => all-season)

Comment: That's what I fail to understand. The var_dump for $category gives me string(10) "all-season" string(10) "all-season"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is with the code you've written being run multiple times rather than a variable duplicating a string.

You need to do more checking inside your `pre_get_posts` callback before modifying the query / outputting the string for testing.

Change this:

```
if($query->is_search()) {
```

To:

```
if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
```

I'd also suggest splitting this into two conditionals but I didn't want to overcomplicate things. We're checking we're not in the admin first. It's not relevant to your question but an important check when using `pre_get_posts`. Then we're checking that we're operating on the main query on the page. `pre_get_posts` will fire multiple times on a page load so we have to be sure we're only modifying the main posts loop.

Comment: You are the man Nathan <3, thanks a lot. Now the question remains why the actual query is not working.